# how to retrive all object array with one value?

Tags: php, object

This question is a follow up from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112360/php-multi-dimension-array/17112404?noredirect=1#comment24760136_17112404) Now for my follow up question I also have this object on page:

```
Array
(
    [registrants] => Array
        (
    [0] => Registrant Object
                (
                    [title] => D C
                    [link] => **********
                    [id] => ***************
                    [updated] => 2013-03-06T12:11:49-05:00
                    [lastName] => C
                    [firstName] => D
                    [email] => *********
                    [personalInformation] => PersonalInformation Object
                        (
                            [cellPhone] => 
                            [label] => 
                            [addr1] => 
                            [addr2] => 
                            [addr3] => 
                            [city] => 
                            [state] => 
                            [postalCode] => 
                            [province] => 
                            [country] => 
                            [phone] => 
                        )

                    [businessInformation] => BusinessInformation Object
                        (
                            [fax] => 
                            [website] => 
                            [blog] => 
                            [company] => 
                            [jobTitle] => 
                            [department] => 
                            [label] => 
                            [addr1] => 
                            [addr2] => 
                            [addr3] => 
                            [city] => 
                            [state] => 
                            [postalCode] => 
                            [province] => 
                            [country] => 
                            [phone] => 
                        )

                    [customInformation1] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [customInformation2] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [registrationStatus] => REGISTERED
                    [registrationDate] => 2013-03-06T12:11:49-05:00
                    [guestCount] => 0
                    [paymentStatus] => NA
                    [orderAmount] => 
                    [currencyType] => 
                    [paymentType] => 
                    [costs] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [1] => Registrant Object
                (
                    [title] => Test Test
                    [link] => ****
                    [id] =>  *************
                    [updated] => 2013-03-06T12:47:47-05:00
                    [lastName] => Test
                    [firstName] => Test
                    [email] =>  ***************
                    [personalInformation] => PersonalInformation Object
                        (
                            [cellPhone] => 
                            [label] => 
                            [addr1] => 
                            [addr2] => 
                            [addr3] => 
                            [city] => 
                            [state] => 
                            [postalCode] => 
                            [province] => 
                            [country] => 
                            [phone] => 
                        )

                    [businessInformation] => BusinessInformation Object
                        (
                            [fax] => 
                            [website] => 
                            [blog] => 
                            [company] => 
                            [jobTitle] => 
                            [department] => 
                            [label] => 
                            [addr1] => 
                            [addr2] => 
                            [addr3] => 
                            [city] => 
                            [state] => 
                            [postalCode] => 
                            [province] => 
                            [country] => 
                            [phone] => 
                        )

                    [customInformation1] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [customInformation2] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [registrationStatus] => REGISTERED
                    [registrationDate] => 2013-03-06T12:47:47-05:00
                    [guestCount] => 0
                    [paymentStatus] => NA
                    [orderAmount] => 
                    [currencyType] => 
                    [paymentType] => 
                    [costs] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

        [nextLink] => 
    )
```

So following the same theory I am retriving the values like this:

```
<?php echo $Registrant->lastName; echo $Registrant->firstName; echo $Registrant->email; ?>
```

but this only retrieves the first lastname and firstname from [0] => Registrant Object not from [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112360/php-multi-dimension-array/17112404?noredirect=1#comment24760136_17112404) => Registrant Object how to i get all of the first names and last names?
Thank everyone for there interest and there time. 
Kind regards 
Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explain your scenario a bit further than other answers.

You have an array of (Registrant) objects here. This is actually an associative array (as all PHP arrays) with indices from 0 - 1.

```
$registrantObjects[0] // would give first Registrant object
$registrantObjects[1] // would give second Registrant object
```

You can access them both. But if you want to iterate the array (i.e. going over all elements and do the same for each one), you should use a loop.
PHP has a nice *foreach* loop for this use case:

```
foreach ($registrantObjects as $registrant) {
  // $registrant is a Registrant object here
  echo $registrant->lastName;
}
```

You could also try this:

```
foreach ($registrantObjects as $index => $registrant) {
  // $registrant is a also Registrant object here
  // But we have a variable $index, too. It represents the current 'key'
  // We have a normal (numbered) array thus the keys are [0..1]

  echo $registrant->lastName;
}
```

And both loops are equal to this *for* loop:

```
for ($i = 0, $len = count($registrantObjects); $i < $len; $i++) {
  // $registrantObjects[$i] gives a Registrant object
}
```

Comment: First things to check: 1.) Have you `error_reporting(true)` set at the top of your script? 2.) Have you switched `display_errors` off in your *php.ini*? You would usually see an error if you follow point #1 and #2. Furthermore, check that *$registrantObjects* is really what you think it is: use `var_dump($registrantObjects);`.

Comment: i also have this on page: 
// get registrant details
$Registrant = $ConstantContact->getRegistrantDetails($registrants['registrants'][0]); could this be causing a conflict of some type, i'm fumbling in the dark here thank you for your help.

Comment: ok i made a small edit to the question the Registrant was inside of Array
(
    [registrants] => Array
        (

Comment: @vimes1984 Please try replacing `$registrantObjects` by `$registrants['registrants']`.

Comment: @vimes1984 Because the variable `$registrantObjects` actually didn't exist. Dany Caissy and I only took that name as an example for you.

Comment: thank you makes perfect sense, How would i display the keys along with the relvant title as well?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31780/discussion-between-vimes1984-and-comfreek)

Answer (score 3):

Lets say the object you printed is "$RegistrantObjects"

You can do the following thing :

```
foreach ($RegistrantObjects as $registrant)
{
    echo $registrant->lastName;
}
```

Within the foreach, the $registrant object will be accessible the same way that you code accesses it.

Comment: small typo: In `foreach()` it should be `$RegistrantObjects` and not `$registrantObjects`

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code;

```
<?php 
    foreach($Registrant as $reg) {
        echo $reg->firstname;
        echo $reg->lastname;
    }
?>
```