# php key values and first value follow?

Tags: php, arrays

This question is a follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17113178/how-to-retrive-all-object-array-with-one-value/17113451?noredirect=1#comment24762369_17113451).
I have returned my variables as needed and reiterated along the array as [@ComFreek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603003/comfreek) suggested.
Now, all I have left to do is echo the indices and the title from the following array:

```
    Array  (  [events] => Array  (  [0] => Event Object  (  [title] => A Celebration of Our Achievements Party  [name] => Copy of Copy of Mar 05, 2013 - TEST3  [description] =>  [registered] => 2  [createdDate]
=> 2013-03-06T11:39:00.182-05:00  [status] => COMPLETE  [eventType] => OTHER  [eventLocation] => EventLocation Object 

) 

[1] => Event Object  (  [title] => Test Event  [name] => Copy of Copy of Mar 05, 2013 - TEST3  [description] =>  [registered] => 2  [createdDate] => 2013-03-06T11:39:00.182-05:00  [status] => COMPLETE  [eventType] => OTHER  [eventLocation] => EventLocation Object  )
```

How do I do this?
Chris

Comment: The series of questions leading to this suggest that you need to hit the books and learn about iteration. These are pretty basic questions you're asking.

Comment: I agree with Barmar, you should really hit the books. Stack Overflow isn't a place to ask people to do your homework, it's there for legitimate questions that other people may have in the future. Anything that can be found with a quick google search, or anything very basic to a language should not be asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be easy as this:

```
foreach ($events['events'] as $index => $event) { 
  echo "[$index] ", $event->title, "<br/>"; 
}
```

Will output:

```
[0] A Celebration of Our Achievements Party
[1] ...
```